# Show that the following system: $x= \frac{\sin(x+y)}{2}, y= \frac{\cos(x-y)}{2} $ admits at most one solution

Tags: functions, derivatives, systems-of-equations

**Question:**
Show that the following system: $x= \frac{\sin(x+y)}{2},  y= \frac{\cos(x-y)}{2} $ admits at most one solution.

I have tried to solve this question by bounding the norm of the differential of $$f(x;y)=\frac{1}{2} (\sin(x+y);\cos(x-y)),$$ but I am stuck. I will be really happy if someone can help me please.

Thank you.

Comment: Showing $f(x;y)$ is a contraction mapping could work.

Comment: @Andrew thant I am going to try!

Comment: Set $u = x+y, \, v = x-y$ and rewrite the problem in terms of these new variables. Then use suitable trig identities. After that prep work show it's a contraction.

Comment: @Andrew can you check the answer I ve written below

Comment: @HansEngler I ve all ready written a proof using the tip Andrew gave me but I will be happy to read your answer :-)

Comment: FWIW, the numerical solution is $x \approx 0.3864507955024854$, $y \approx 0.496950555514389$.

Answer (score 1):

First of all we know that $(\mathbb{R}^N; ||.||) $ is complete.

$Df(x;y)=Jf(x;y)=\frac{1}{2} \begin{pmatrix}
cos(x+y) & cos(x+y) \\ 
 -sin(x-y)& sin(x-y) 
\end{pmatrix}$
Hence $||Df(x;y)||_{\infty} \leq \frac {1}{2} Max (|cos(x+y)|;|sin(x-y)|) \leq \frac{1}{2}$
As it is true $\forall  (x;y), (w;z) \in  \mathbb{R^2}$ by the Mean value theorem we get that $|| f(x;y) -f(w;z)||_{\infty} \leq || (x;y) -(w;z)||_{\infty} \frac {1}{2} $. Hence $f$ is a contraction mapping.

Hence by the fixed point theorem this finish the question.

Is it correct?

Comment: I think you have a gap in your otherwise correct proof: You need to show that a suitable operator norm of $Df$ is $<1$, not just any norm. E.g. wrt. to the Euclidean norm on $\mathbb{R}^2$, one would look at the largest singular value of $Df(x,y)$, i.e. the square root of the large eigenvalue of $Df(x,y) \cdot  Df(x,y)^T$. This turns out to be very easy, give it a try, The rest of your argument then is unchanged